# Nginx http redirect to https doesn't work

Tags: nginx, graphite

I am using nginx reverse proxy for my graphite web. 
My nginx.conf looks somewhat like this

```
server {
           listen 8081;
           server_name myserver.com;
           return 301 https://$host:5000$request_uri;
       }

 server {
       listen 5000 ssl;
       server_name myserver.com;

       location / {
           proxy_pass                 http://127.0.0.1:8080;
           proxy_set_header           X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
           proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
           proxy_set_header           X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
           proxy_set_header           Host  $host;


           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type';
           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

           # here comes the basic auth, after the options part
           auth_basic            'Restricted';
           auth_basic_user_file  path/to/.htpasswd;

       }

       ssl    on;
       ssl_certificate    path/to/crt;
       ssl_certificate_key    path/to/key;
   }
```

I start using my site on https://host:5000 and i want any http requests to this site to be redirected as a https request. As of now i see that it gets redirected to http://host/

This happens only during login and logout.

I saw many examples where they used port 80 for listening to http traffic but i cannot use that port as some other application is already using that.

Can someone please help me out in this?

Comment: have you tried changing 80 to whatever port your server is listening in nginx server settings ?

Comment: I do all the changes i need in the conf file. Here i have specified port 8081 for http traffic.

Comment: what is running on 8081 ? That is not receiving request forwarded ?

Comment: There is nothing running on 8081. It's purpose is to redirect http traffic on port5000 as https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try using `$server_name` instead of `$host`, for example:

```
server {
   listen 8081;
   server_name myserver.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name:5000$request_uri;
}
```

You can indeed put your domain directly on the redirect for example:

```
return 301 https://myserver.com:5000$request_uri;
```

Probably this is not your case but since you are using different ports may be worth to check the `error_page 497`, this is mainly used when you want to process plain HTTP request which has been sent to HTTPS port:

```
server {
  listen      8081 ssl;
  server_name your.site.tld;
  ssl         on;
  ...
  error_page  497 https://$host:5000$request_uri;
  ...
}
```

To know more about the `497` check the "Error Processing"  section in http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html

Comment: Well, using the error_page seems to do the trick for me. There was no need of another 8081 port again. Thanks